# Creating Custom Header in MS Visual Basic for Application

Tags: vba, header-files, vbe

I am going through learning modules and the author of the VBA tutorials did something cool.

He clicked the "Insert Code Element Header" button and it automatically pasted something he made himself as a standard header (he uses repeatedly).

I've been googling, but I can't seem to figure out how he did it.

I am using Office 2013, and MS VB for Apps version 7.1, his version does seem older, maybe version 5.0/6.0, he doesn't state it. What he does is convenient because he just removes the comment for stuff that he knows hes going to use on most projects, whether they are modules, objects, or class modules.

When I click the Insert Header button, it only gives me these options, that i cannot add to:

[image: MSVBAmyHeader]

Here's a screenshot of what his VBA looks like, and the header:

[image: MSVBA]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you! this helps plenty! sorry for late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TimWilliams linked to the tools that I use in my development. That toolset has exactly what you're for.

But if you're looking for the details of how the VBA Editor is modified (as shown in your tutorial and in MZTools), you should read about the `VBE Object` in the [MS Reference Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443984(v=vs.60).aspx). Chip Pearson also has an excellent intro to some of the concepts in [modifying the VBA programming environment](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) too.

Comment: so sorry for late response, thank you Peter! this and what Tim posted are exactly what I was looking for! this helps me out a bunnch especially with other stuff I wasn't aware of lol. thanks again